# How to rebuild the first screen with data from second screen?

Tags: flutter

i have my first page(two page total),inside the screen i have a textbox and two buttons(add button and nextpage button),when i type some words in textbox and click add button it will add that text in same screen below as notes,now i am clicking next page button it will take me to second page using *Navigator.push("code")*,now in this second page i have a textbox and only one button(add button),if i type some words and click add button now it will have to change the first page notes data.now i click the back button in appbar which i got by using navigator.push(),the first page will have to render with updated data.so any idea on how do to this?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter based on unidirectional data flow like React, so basically you pass data to your child widget, not the other way around. That's why there are many state management libraries and architectures available.

However, since your example is simple, before you deep dive into state management methods, I'll suggest couple of things to solve your problem.

You can pass a callback function to your second screen from your first screen. So you have a function in your first screen, which calls its `setState` method inside. You pass that function the second screen and second screen calls it with some values and done.

Other option is, you can write your own navigate back function and icon for the appbar which will override the default one.

And pass the result on Navigator.pop

```
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.pop(context, 'data!');
  },
```

Here's the official documentation: [Return data from a screen](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data)